# Echo every variable in an array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach, echo

I'm trying to remove whitespaces and replace this with a '-' from every variale in an array. However I only get the last variable of the array.

My code:

```
<ul class="gap-items">
<?php 
    while ($query->have_posts()): 
        $query->the_post(); 
        $post_type = get_post_type( get_the_ID() );   

        $key = 'field_5208f1f811702';
        $value = get_field($key);

        var_dump($value);

        foreach ($value as $label) {
            $label = strtolower($label);

            $label = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $label);

            //Clean up multiple dashes or whitespaces
            $label = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $label);

            //Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
            $label = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $label);

            var_dump($label);
        }
?>
        <!-- Loop posts -->     
        <li class="item <?php echo $post_type ?> <?php echo $label ?>" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-permalink="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

So`$value` is an array. For every variable I'm removing the whitespace and replace it by a dash. I need to echo every variable outside the foreach function. I also tried to implode the variable first but with no results. How to do this? Thanks!

**Edit:** The first `var_dump($value);` gives me an array like: 
`array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "Option 3"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "Option 4"
}`

the var_dump($label) gives: 
`string(8) "option-3"
string(8) "option-4"`

I want to echo just this: *option-3 option-4*

Comment: Why can't you just put the <li> tag in the foreach? (wrap it with end-php and start-php tags).

Comment: One thing I notice in your new edit with the while is you're using the alternate syntax (`while ():`) instead of using the standard syntax and I don't see and `endwhile;` in your code sample which makes it incomplete. But you're looping in the while with a foreach inside of the while, is that a correct assumption? Also, try and format your code neatly when posting here, that can help you find issues and it aids in our ability to follow along with what you're doing.

Comment: In addition to the above, since this isn't a complete snippet, can you make a small snippet with that is executable that we can test and describe better what kind of outcome you'd like? As it stands I cannot run your code and see your results therefor it makes it that much harder for me to try and pinpoint where your error may lie.

Answer (score 3):

You are only getting the last one because your echo line:

```
<li class="item <?php echo $post_type ?> <?php echo $label ?>"></li>
```

Is placed **after** your foreach loop. So it's using the last values set for `$label` and `$post_type`. Try placing that inside your loop so the echo is generated every time you loop over the list.

You should end up with something like the following:

```
$value = get_field($key);

foreach ($value as $label) {
    $label = strtolower($label);

    $label = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $label);

    //Clean up multiple dashes or whitespaces
    $label = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $label);

    //Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
    $label = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $label);


    echo "<li class=\"item $post_type $label\"></li>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This might work indeed. But what if you want to put this outside the loop? I that possible?

Comment: If you're printing an `li` for each item in the array you never want to put it outside of the loop. Otherwise you will never end up with all the values echoed. There will always need to be some kind of loop to display an unknown number of items.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still not getting what I want. Maybe it's because the list is generated by a while function (see the edit in my question).

Comment: In further addendum to what I've posted above on your original question (as comments), now that I more of an understanding of what you're doing. You would still need to output the <li> in ever iteration of the foreach as you're using a variable generated in the foreach in your output. If you only want one (1) <li> per while iteration then your current format is doing exactly as you intended

Answer (score 1):

You closed the foreach loop too early:

```
$value = get_field($key);

foreach ($value as $label) {
$label = strtolower($label);

$label = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $label);

//Clean up multiple dashes or whitespaces
$label = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $label);

//Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
$label = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $label);


echo "<li class='item $post_type $label'></li>"
}
```

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong but I don't think variables are interpolated in single quoted strings. I'm not a PHP expert but I know several languages use follow that same construct.

Comment: I usually don't really bother about using either ' or " (in case i copied old html wich used "), and it never broke with me. But i might be wrong

Comment: It doesn't appear to work, [here's the test at phpFiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ws0-fyk). Something to keep in mind in the future.

Comment: Thanks izuriel, i always use ' in html when writing myself and if someone else wrote it, i'm just to lazy to rewrite or \".

Comment: In further addendum to what I've posted above on your original question (as comments), now that I more of an understanding of what you're doing. You would still need to output the `<li>` in ever iteration of the `foreach` as you're using a variable generated in the `foreach` in your output. If you only want one (1) `<li>` per while iteration then your current format is doing exactly as you intended.

Comment: Isn't it the case that you need a seperate <li> for every iteration 90% of the time? (I might not have understood you question right)

Comment: My sincerest apologies, that was completely intended to be added to my answer. That has nothing to do with you I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use the str_replace function, it takes a string and replaces all occurrences.

```
str_replace(' ','-',$label)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use `print_r()`. That will print the entire array with the keys and values.

So after the `foreach`, you would write:

`print_r($value);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php